# I have an issue with my radio buttons messagebox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

```
 If RB_Male.Checked Or RB_Female.Checked = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please select your gender")
    ElseIf RB_Male.Checked = False Or RB_Female.Checked = True Then
    ElseIf RB_Male.Checked = True Or RB_Female.Checked = False Then

    End If
```

I have an issue as in, I want my error message to only pop up when both radio buttons are not selected. The code above allows the messagebox to pop up even when one of the radio buttons are selected which I don't want happening. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your first IF statement says that if RB_Male IS checked or RB_Female is not checked.

Comment: If you set one or the other to checked in the design IDE, there can never be the case of none being picked.  Its part of the idiom of RadioButtons

Comment: This is true, and it would completely remove the need for an error message at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if neither button is checked:

```
If Not (RB_Male.Checked AndAlso RB_Female.Checked) Then
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If (NOT RB_Male.Checked) ANDALSO (NOT RB_Female.Checked) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please select your gender")
ElseIf RB_Male.Checked = False Or RB_Female.Checked = True Then
ElseIf RB_Male.Checked = True Or RB_Female.Checked = False Then

End If
```